# elk not working - AnalyticsDataPublisher is not initialized

Tags: wso2, analytics, wso2-api-manager, elk

Since I am in an air gapped environment I don't have access to choreo cloud, so my best option is using the ELK stack.
My ELK stack is only logstash to opensearch.

When I try an API it won't stop loading and in the gateway pod I get this error:

```
ERROR - api_test AnalyticsDataPublisher is not initialized.
```

I use logstash container witch shares logs mount with apim cp container logs. In deployment.toml, I have it configured like this:

```
[apim.analytics]
enabled = true
type = "elk"
```

In log4j2.properties I have it configured like this:

```
appender.APIM_METRICS_APPENDER.type = RollingFile
appender.APIM_METRICS_APPENDER.name = APIM_METRICS_APPENDER
appender.APIM_METRICS_APPENDER.fileName = ${sys:carbon.home}/repository/logs/apim_metrics.log
appender.APIM_METRICS_APPENDER.filePattern = ${sys:carbon.home}/repository/logs/apim_metrics-%d{MM-dd-yyyy}-%i.log
appender.APIM_METRICS_APPENDER.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.APIM_METRICS_APPENDER.layout.pattern = %d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} [%X{ip}-%X{host}] [%t] %5p %c{1} %m%n
appender.APIM_METRICS_APPENDER.policies.type = Policies
appender.APIM_METRICS_APPENDER.policies.time.type = TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.APIM_METRICS_APPENDER.policies.time.interval = 1
appender.APIM_METRICS_APPENDER.policies.time.modulate = true
appender.APIM_METRICS_APPENDER.policies.size.type = SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.APIM_METRICS_APPENDER.policies.size.size=1000MB
appender.APIM_METRICS_APPENDER.strategy.type = DefaultRolloverStrategy
appender.APIM_METRICS_APPENDER.strategy.max = 10
loggers = reporter, ...(list of other available loggers)
logger.reporter.name = org.wso2.am.analytics.publisher.reporter.elk
logger.reporter.level = INFO 
logger.reporter.additivity = false
logger.reporter.appenderRef.APIM_METRICS_APPENDER.ref = APIM_METRICS_APPENDER
```

and in logstash.conf I have it configured like this:

```
input {
    file {
        add_field => {
                instance_name => "${NODE_ID}"
                instance_IP => "${NODE_IP}"
               }
        type => "wso2"
        start_position => "beginning"
        path => "usr/share/logstash/wso2-logs/apim_metrics.log"
        codec => multiline {
              pattern => "^TID"
              negate => true
              what => "previous"
             }
       }
}

filter {
    grok {
        match => ["message", "%{GREEDYDATA:UNWANTED}\ apimMetrics:%{GREEDYDATA:apimMetrics}\, %{GREEDYDATA:UNWANTED} \:%{GREEDYDATA:properties}"]
    }
    json {
        source => "properties"
    }
}
output {
    if [apimMetrics] == " apim:response" {
        opensearch {
            hosts => ["http://{ELK_URL}:9200"]
            index => "apim_event_response"
            user => "open"
            password => "Admin1234"
        }
    } else if [apimMetrics] == " apim:faulty" {
        opensearch {
            hosts => ["http://{ELK_URL}:9200"]
            index => "apim_event_faulty"
            user => "elastic"
            password => "Admin1234"
        }
    }
}
```

Any help on the matter will be highly appreciated as I couldn't find any knowledge on this error on the internet.